# instalacion de cliente mongodb en la terminal windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, gitlab

¿Por que el mi cliente no se quiere  conectar con mi servidor mongodb por terminal de windows ?
[image: cliente]

[image: servidor]

Answer (score 0):

Te redirecciono a una respuesta en Stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243731/mongodb-cannot-start-server-the-default-storage-engine-wiredtiger-is-not-avai

La solución se encuentra en el primer comentario

> Write the command as follows in your Mongo/bin directory:

```
mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath [your-path]
```

El problema no esta en el cliente que no se puede conectar, sino en el servidor que no puede "arrancar".

Además como sugerencia, te recomendaría (si no hay un impedimento) conectarte con el cliente Robo3T de MongoDB es mas interactivo y no tiene muchas variantes con respecto a la administración por consola.
Saludos.